# undefined index error after multidimensional array check

Tags: isset

why I am getting undefined index error ?

```
if(isset($arr["val"][3])
{ 
$res =isset($arr["val"][3]["body"]) ? $arr["val"][3]["body"] : "";

}
```

error is..

*Undefined index: body SOURCE: ... on line ....*

Tried with array_key_exists - the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a missing bracket in the if clause:

if(isset($arr["val"][3])**)**

can you show the content of the array, `echo var_dump($arr);`

Comment: A part of array that causes this error, contains object and doesn't containt "body" index at all

Comment: I also tried with property_exists() it also returns true and  "undefined index" after that

Comment: it should work ideally, try using `if-else` instead of ternary

Comment: take a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow